# Obtain property of a room square

Tags: javascript, screeps

Is there a fast way to get the properties of a certain square in a room (for example, terrain type)? The room.lookAt(x,y) method is really slow. It wouldn't be this slow if it just needed to do an array lookup. Terrain type is something that never changes so it wouldn't need to recalculate this every time. Also, even dynamic properties like having a creep on a certain square would not take much time to query if the underlying data would be stored in a different way.

Would it be possible to implement a fast way to obtain this data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. If the `RoomPosition` class could return what objects it contains, it would probably be faster, but otherwise I can't think of any faster way to accomplish this and the docs don't actually mention any other possibilities.

Comment: Yes, that'd be my suggestion. The docs don't mention any other possibility, so my question was more aimed towards the developers if they could add such a faster way. Then it'd be possible to actually create other AI algorithms yourself, like diffusion-based approaches. Currently, these are way too slow, because they require looking at every square in the room once. This doesn't have to be that slow.